# Angular2 / ionic2 Protect a token from being visible in the code

Tags: angular, token, ionic2

I have a question about Ionic2 / Angular2. I'm doing an API call from my Ionic application. This call requires a private token. 
Of course, this token is in a `controller` but I'd need it to be invisible in the generated JS sources.

Is there a way to do so?

Julian

Comment: If it's a token you use to make an API call to a third party, do it on the server instead of on the client

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The thing is that I'm using Ionic to embed this code inside my app. So my token and API call will be visible for people who unpack my app. In a native app, this token is compiled in a binary. Here it's not.